# If every infinte subset of E has a limit point in E then E is compact in X

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let X be a metric space. Show that a subset E of X is compact if and
only if every infinite subset of E has a limit point in E.
How to prove the converse statement ?
i.e. if every infinite subset of E has a limit point in E then E is compact in X.
I want to prove from the definition of compact sets.

Comment: What is your definition of compact sets?

Comment: If every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: See [here](http://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18.100B/HW4-solved.pdf)

Comment: Take a sequence in your space. If its range is finite, it has a convergent subsequence. If not, the range is infinite and has a limit point. You can find a subsequence converging to the limit point. Hence, every sequence has a convergent subsequence and the space is compact.

Comment: @Math_QED A space can be [sequentially compact and not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152447/compactness-sequentially-compact). At best, what you have done is to prove that *limit point compact* implies *sequentially compact* in a metric space. But even for that you only said "You can find a subsequence ..." without really saying why.

Comment: The OP said that $X$ is a metric space (and the question is tagged accordingly), in which the two compactness notions are equivalent. Secondly, I just gave a hint. The details are left as an exercice for the OP.

Comment: @Math_QED The question is showing that equivalence, for which there is no hint in your comment.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773484/let-x-be-a-metric-space-in-which-every-infinite-subset-has-a-limit-point-prove?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

First note that by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430113/is-a-separable-and-metrizable-space-second-countable/2812134#2812134) we know that if $X$ limit point compact (i.e. every infinite set has a limit point), then $X$ is Lindelöf (i.e. every open cover has a countable subcover), otherwise $X$ would have a closed and discrete uncountable subspace, contradicting the limit point compactness.

Then as metric spaces are $T_1$, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1817493/4280) shows that a limit point compact metric $X$ is also countably compact (every countable cover has a finite subcover).

And clearly then $X$ is compact (we reduce an open cover to a countable one via Lindelöfness, and then to a finite one using countable compactness). Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2234332/4280) for an overview of similar ideas.